# Test of reducer returns the results which are not equal to expected

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, reduce, react-testing-library

I try to test my reducer with react testing library and I don't understand why I get results that are not equal to the expected. Please could you explain to me?

my reducer

```
export const myReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'GET_DATA':
            return [...payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

my test

```
import { mockedState } from 'mocks';

import {
    myReducer,
    GET_DATA,
} from 'store';

const initialState = []

describe('reducer', () => {

  it('should get data', () => {
    const getAction = {
      type: GET_DATA,
      payload: mockedState.data,
    };
    expect(myReducer(initialState, getAction )).toEqual([...mockedState.data]);
  });
})
```

Comment: It would seem the `GET_DATA` in your test is not necessarily a string. What is `GET_DATA` in `store`?

Comment: Show the test result, the assertion result. Maybe it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer, you are using a string `"GET_DATA"` in your switch case. But from the look of your test your action type is a variable `GET_DATA`. Try changing your reducer's first case to be

```js
case GET_DATA: //remove the quotes
```

where `GET_DATA` is from 'store'.

Actually, I just remembered case for a switch statement must be a constant. So just make sure your GET_DATA from store is actually equal to "GET_DATA".

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to revolve around when an iterable `a` is not 'shallow' equal to `[...a]`. If `a` is an array that should always be the case but for any other iterable it's not.

I suspect `mockedState.data` is not an array in the failing test.

For example:

```
const a = 'hello';
const b = [...a];        // ["h","e","l","l","o"]
```

In this case a does not equal b.